# trying to break the string into multiple sections

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, coldfusion, lucee

I have the string value as:

```
Half Day Morning (9:00 AM - 11:30 AM)  (M/T/W/TH/F)
```

i am using coldfusion code using `replace` but that is not working

using either `javascript` or `jquery` or any server side, i am trying to break this code it to like this

```
  1. Half Day Morning 
    2. 9:00 AM - 11:30 AM 
    3. M/T/W/TH/F
```

any idea how can i do it, plan to use regex but not sure if the server side regex will make it or not, i a using cold fusion

am i am using a cfoutput query around the rows

Comment: Um... `jquery` is not server-side.

Comment: @expressjs123, _"jquery OR any server side"_.

Comment: It sounded like (javascript, jquery or server side)

Comment: "i am using coldfusion code using `replace` but that is not working".  You say it's not working but you're not showing your code.  I'm pretty sure that's a requirement in asking a question.

Answer (score 3):

You can try this [regex](https://regex101.com/r/wMFHMV/1/) as demonstrated here in PHP.

Outputs:

```
1. Half Day Morning
2. 9:00 AM - 11:30 AM
3. M/T/W/TH/F
```

Code:

```
<?php

$s = 'Half Day Morning (9:00 AM - 11:30 AM)  (M/T/W/TH/F)';


if (preg_match('/([^\(]+)\s+\(([^\)]+)\)\s+\(([^\)]+)\)/', $s, $matches) === FALSE)
// preg_last_error_msg() available since PHP 8 which is now out!
    die('preg_match() failed: ' . preg_last_error_msg());

foreach ($matches as $num => $text)
{
    if ($num)
        echo "$num. $text\n";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

use split() and access it by index value

```js
function myFunction() {
  var str = "Half Day Morning (9:00 AM - 11:30 AM)  (M/T/W/TH/F)";
   str = str.replaceAll(")", "");
   var res = str.split("(");
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "1. "+res[0]+"<br> 2. "+ res[1]+"<br> 3. "+ res[2];
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
 Half Day Morning (9:00 AM - 11:30 AM)  (M/T/W/TH/F)
 <br>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

If the string is always formatted like that with parenthesis a simple split should do the trick

```js
var str = "Half Day Morning (9:00 AM - 11:30 AM)  (M/T/W/TH/F)";
str.replace(")", "");
var res = str.split("(");

var str1 = "1. " + res[0].trim();
var str2 = "2. " + res[1].trim();
var str3 = "3. " + res[2].trim();
```

Answer (score 1):

**Modified to show how to do it with query results**

Here is a way to do it with ColdFusion code:

```
<cfoutput query="NameOfQuery">
    <cfset StringAsList = Replace(FieldFromQuery, ")", "", "all")>
    <cfloop index="LoopCounter" from="1" to="#ListLen(StringAsList, '(')#">
    #LoopCounter#. #ListGetAt(StringAsList, LoopCounter, "(")#<br>
    </cfloop>    
</cfoutput>
```

You can mess around with it [here](https://trycf.com/gist/e1297fe105a506188a7467cdf8bf049c/acf2018?theme=monokai).

Comment: but how to ijn a query loop, if i have multiple records and every row has some format like above

Comment: I didn't see that in the original question.

Comment: duh, i forog to mention it in the question, i will edit the question